# Interacting through my list and making news lists based on indexes

Tags: python, list

So i am doing the following interation.

```
for i in cleaned_rows:
    for j in i:
        print(j)
```

Which results in the following

```
2021-12-28T20:44:35.262Z
2021-12-28
claroresidentialsales@msging.net
e2df35d4-66a5-4470-8b29-b04b3f9f907d@tunnel.msging.net
onboarding return-start view
Exibicao
{city:null
2021-12-28T20:44:35.733Z
2021-12-28
claroresidentialsales@msging.net
e2df35d4-66a5-4470-8b29-b04b3f9f907d@tunnel.msging.net
onboarding segment-confirmation origin
onboarding return-start
{city:null
2021-12-28T20:44:35.412Z
2021-12-28
claroresidentialsales@msging.net
e2df35d4-66a5-4470-8b29-b04b3f9f907d@tunnel.msging.net
onboarding return-start origin
product-selection combos-packages-redirection
{city:null
```

For those curious this is what i[0] looks like:

```
    [2021-12-28T20:44:35.262Z
    2021-12-28
    claroresidentialsales@msging.net
    e2df35d4-66a5-4470-8b29-b04b3f9f907d@tunnel.msging.net
    onboarding return-start view
    Exibicao
    {city:null]
```

As you can see after the seventh value it repeats itself, basically another list is interated through. The thing is i want to do is pick the first index from my first list, and associate it to the following first index from the others lists and put into a list, ignoring the suceding indexes. The same goes to the second index from my first list, associate to the following second indexes appending it a list, and it goes unto the seventh index or 'sixth'. Hope you guys help me.

Desired outcome:

```
List 1 : [2021-12-28T20:44:35.262Z,2021-12-28T20:44:35.733Z,2021-12-28T20:44:35.412Z]
List 2: [2021-12-28,2021-12-28,2021-12-28]
```

And it goes

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your desired output explanation. Can you provide a sample output?

Comment: Sure thingy i am gonna make and edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a list of list e.g. `data = [[a1, b1, c1], [a2, b2, c2], [a3, b3, c3], ...]` you can obtain the output `separated = [[a1, a2, a3, ...], [b1, b2, b3, ...], [c1, c2, c3, ...]` by `list(map(list, zip(*data)))`

The `*` operator provides an iterator over `data` which provides each element of `data`, i.e., each of the inner lists, separately to the zip function.

The `zip` function takes multiple iterable objects and provides tuple of their elements in order, i.e, first tuple is the first element of each list.

We turn the tuples into lists by `map` and apply `list` function to each.

We turn the resulting `map` output into a `list`.

Note that for this to work you require all inner lists to have the same number of elements as `zip` will not return an nth tuple if any of the inner lists do not have an nth element.

Comment: Didnt quite work mate, Got the following output.  As i tried to print out the first statement                                         
cleaned_rows[0] = ['2021-12-28T20 44 35.262Z', '2021-12-28']. Code: cleaned_rows = list(map(list, zip(*cleaned_rows)))

Comment: The input cleaned_rows is a list of lists? Ea

Comment: From the original question you have `i[0]` as a list of 7 itself. If this is so then this should work on `*i`.